# aws_storagegateway_gateway SMB share File/directory access controlled by option with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-storage-gateway

I am unsing below terraform code to create aws file storage gateway. I am able to create the SMB file share but the settings for **File/directory access controlled by** : **POSIX permissions** But I wanted to update this with **Windows Access Control Lists**.

Try to check https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/storagegateway_smb_file_share.html but didnt find the right argument to implement this.

Can someone help me on this.

```
resource "aws_storagegateway_gateway" "gateway" {
  gateway_ip_address = var.gateway_ip_address
  gateway_name       = var.gateway_name
  gateway_timezone   = var.gateway_timezone
  gateway_type       = "FILE_S3"

  smb_active_directory_settings {
  domain_name        = var.domain
  username           = var.domain_username
  password           = var.domain_password
  }
}

resource "aws_storagegateway_smb_file_share" "storage_gw" {
  authentication  = "ActiveDirectory"
  gateway_arn     = aws_storagegateway_gateway.gateway.arn
  default_storage_class = "S3_STANDARD_IA"
  location_arn    = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
  role_arn        = aws_iam_role.gateway.arn
  valid_user_list = ["@application_group"]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I could able to solve this issue with below cli command

aws storagegateway update-smb-file-share --file-share-arn arn:aws:storagegateway:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxx:gateway/sgw-xxxxxx --smbacl-enabled

Answer (score 1):

I could able to solve this issue with below cli command

```
aws storagegateway update-smb-file-share --file-share-arn arn:aws:storagegateway:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxx:gateway/sgw-xxxxxx --smbacl-enabled
```